# why do I need a timeout when modifying the dom in angular

Tags: angularjs

Like the headline says, I don't understand why I need a $timeout when manipulating the DOM inside a directive's link function.

The code below works.
The element in question is a 1x1 div that holds a container for a video plugin.
If I remove the $timeout, the element is not resized and is not visible.
Removing the $timeout and replacing it with $rootScope.$apply() does not work. There is no ajax calls being waited on. I simply want to resize an element on a user action.

My problem is that the timeout time is really arbitrary and on older browsers running on older computers I need a bigger timeout value in the range of 1500ms, which works about 90% of the time. Even 1500ms is ridiculous and I certainly don't want to make it greater.

```js
var containerBoundingBox;
$timeout(function () {
  containerBoundingBox = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  $log.warn('containerBoundingBox: ', containerBoundingBox);
  getActiveVideoElement().css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'z-index': 1000000,
    'top': containerBoundingBox.top + 'px',
    'left': containerBoundingBox.left + 'px',
    'width': containerBoundingBox.width + 'px',
    'height': containerBoundingBox.height + 'px'
  });
}, 100);
```

The element code, taken from a live page:
It is the div I'm resizing not the object tag.

```html
<div id="pluginContainer"
     class="pluginContainer ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"
     style="position: fixed; top: 1px; left: 1px; width: 1px; height: 1px; z-index: 1000000;">
    <object type="application/x-xxxx"
            id="xxxxxPlugin"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    ></object>
</div>
```

Comment: It totally depends on video plugin, and this insignificant detail was omitted in the question.

Comment: Please provide more code. If the `getActiveVideoElement()` returns jQuery object I think it should work without $timeout or $apply()

Comment: the element is a jqLite object, were banned from using jQuery.

Comment: Like @estus has written it can depend on video plugin

Comment: sorry got interruped, the video element, I dont think enters intot it. I will try to edit the question and add the html code for the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout is required to allow the DOM manipulation from the last angularjs digest cycle to complete.  Without this you won't see any changes in height, text, style, class, etc.

Also, if you don't include a time after the timeout, the timeout will occur immediately after the digest completes.  There was one case were we needed access outside of this and used an undocumented feature $$postDigest, this allowed us to gather data from the digest without including browser events.

Comment: tried to remove the timeout value, but the display still did not update. Also tried from [http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/)   `code// Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive
        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest(); code` and it did not work either

Comment: I would need to see more of the code, if you can build a working prototype I can help debug.   BTW, DOM manipulation is very frowned upon in angular, you're supposed to let angular do the work.   Only cases I ran into this not being possible was with fixed positioned items based on other items.

Comment: We had a similar issue not sure if this would help, but we used a style to handle this for iframes.   element {min-width: 100vw !important; min-height: 100vh !important; }

Comment: Last option, which I've done before is keep the item on a 50ms interval, then you know it'll be forced to the right size.   This worked for me as I have a fixed position item that is resizing and I need to adjust the top/height/etc under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In angular there are digest cycles which are usually caused by DOM manipulation that is annotated with bindings which are causing the page/part of the page to redraw. 
When you perform an operation which is not related to the internal mechanism of angular then the framework does not know that a digest cycle should be initiated and therefore you need sometimes to tell it explicitly to do so.

Comment: The problem is not about digest I think.

Comment: Maybe you replaced an element with a new one using templates/cloneNode etc. I would save the element ref in a local variable and compare it to the one in the DOM later on. Anyway I think that you need to supply more details regarding the issue.

Comment: @latata I belive you are correct. Removing the timeout value, which should do fire the timeout immediatly after the $digest cycle, as Vince pointed out, results in the display not being updated, unless I do something like manually resize the browser window.